# vue3.2x use <script setup>， Build does not resolve computed properties in :src="require()"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

vue 3.2.31
**use <script setup>**

```
  <template>
    <img :src="require(`@/assets/images/icon_num_${state.lotteryNum}.png`)" alt="" />
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import {reactive} from 'vue'
const state = reactive({
    lotteryNum:1,
})
</script>
```

When running locally, there is no problem. But after packaging, the console will report an error when running online.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZAZD.png)

error message： ReferenceError: _unref is not defined

I tried not to use <script setup>，There is no problem with running locally, and there is no problem with running after packaging。

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I am also facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this way like
 `<img :src="require('@/assets/images/icon_num_'+state.lotteryNum+'.png')" alt="" />`